# Linq запрос к коллекции

Tags: c#, linq, enum

Есть коллекция:

```
private Dictionary<string, cFiles> files= new Dictionary<string, cFiles>();
```

cFiles представляет из себя класс, в котором три поля: Status (enum), Name (string), Root (string)
Как подсчитать количество элементов в коллекции с статусом Status.finished (enum)?

Answer (score 5):

Используем свойство `Value` элемента словаря:

```
files.Where(x=>x.Value?.Status==Status.finished).Count();
```

Элвис-оператор `?.` применим на случай, если в словаре будет неинициализированный экземпляр.

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться множеством значений словаря ([`Dictionary.Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx)) и методом [`Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx), который принимает условие для подсчета.

Получится что-то вроде:

```
var finishedFilesCount = files.Values.Count(f=>f.Status == Status.Finished);
```